# Android Maps KML Handler

Tags: android, kml, android-maps

Ok so at the moment I'm getting a null pointer exception when adding to the list of overlays. I've declared this at the top of the map activity class:

```
private static List<Overlay> mOverlays;
```

And then further down I've got this for my source/ from point:

```
Drawable fromDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_blue);
OverlayItem fromOverlayItem = new OverlayItem(fromGeoPoint, "Hello!", "This is your current Location.");
MapWhatsNearOverlay fromItemizedOverlay = new MapWhatsNearOverlay(fromDrawable);
mOverlays.add(fromItemizedOverlay);

connectAsyncTask _connectAsyncTask = new connectAsyncTask();
_connectAsyncTask.execute();
mMapView.getOverlays().add((Overlay) mOverlays);
```

And the same for the destination as well, but the null pointer exception pops up when processing the bottom line of code.

Comment: This question is getting little interest because it is including unnecessarily huge segment of code. Please post only relevant parts. [Stack Overflow is not going to read all that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129787)

Comment: Sorry - I never know how much code people need to see.. I've cut it down anyway so hopefully that'll help. Thanks Rajesh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this [link](http://asmncl.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-draw-route-map-between-two.html) to draw driving path in your application. You just need to add the four classes present in the link in your project and call the below lines when you need to display the route.

```
SharedData data = SharedData.getInstance();
data.setAPIKEY("0RUTLH7cqd6yrZ0FdS0NfQMO3lioiCbnH-BpNQQ");//set your map key here
data.setSrc_lat(17);//set your src lat
data.setSrc_lng(78);//set your src lng
data.setDest_lat(18);//set your dest lat
data.setDest_lng(77);//set your dest lng
startActivity(new Intent(YourActivity.this,RoutePath.class));//add RoutePath in your manifeast file
```

//Also add the permission to your manifeast file

Comment: Thanks Agarwal. I've already got my permissions and the API key in place. I'll have a go at incorporating this into the project and let you know how it goes

Comment: Agarwal - I've mostly incorporated the example into my code, but for a couple of errors in the RoutePath class that's stopping me from testing. They're on the lines with 'srcitemizedOverlay.addOverlay(srcoverlayitem); and destitemizedOverlay.addOverlay(destoverlayitem);' as 'srcitemizedOverlay' and 'destitemizedOverlay' haven't been defined. Do I need to define them as separate OverlayItems or (I'm probably skipping something important by suggesting this..!) can I change the lines below to 'mapOverlays.add(srcoverlayitem/destoverlayitem)'? Thanks again!

Comment: can you tell me in which class these error are? and also updated my blog see it once

Comment: They're just 'cannot be resolved' errors as they haven't previously been defined

Comment: Yep I've found it now and have been able to test. Cool - I've got it working as a separate activity, so now I just need to alter it so the route is worked into the existing map activity. Thanks Agarwal - you've been loads of help!

Comment: Well I'm having lots of trouble getting the code into my activity as I've done thing slightly differently here and there, mainly because of the overlays being implemented a little differently.. I'll keep working on it but may end up posting the code above seeing as the situation's changed

Comment: what you didnt get the routemap?

Comment: It worked when I ran it using startActivity(RouteMap), but I want to have it run as part of my main map activity so I've been trying to merge the RouteMap code into my map activity. I'm probably just being a bit rubbish - I'm still new to Android..

Comment: Thanks for all the help Agarwal! I've changed the code at the top to show where the error occurs.

Comment: And we're done - just needed a bit of tinkering here and there and I'm finally sorted! Thanks again for all your help Agarwal!